# How can I access the response object in DetailView?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-class-based-views

I want to access the response object rendered in a DetailView so that I can manually cache it (and delete it from cache on specific uses).

What's the best way to access the response object that gets created by the DetailView?

Comment: Look into decorators. I'm not sure of your use case, but if you use this same logic in a few places, then a decorator would be well suited to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the response in the `get` or `dispatch` methods:

```
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super(MyDetailView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
        # Do caching stuff here
        return response
```